# In Win7 Pro the computer name is added to the network login so I can't access network computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, login

I'm just trying to login to computers in the workgroup. When the system asks for the login and password it insists on adding my computername to the login which then fails. I've tried editing the settings in the vault but this has no effect. I'm pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

In the username box, enter the name of the computer that you're trying to connect to, then a backslash, then username.

Like this: `WRKGRP-PC\User1`

Comment: The computer adds the computer name by itself - it shows this under the login box before you start. I've been doing this for years under XP etc. and I just can't figure it out. Thanks, BTW.